# (imap.mail.yahoo.com) У меня не заходит ни через программу ни через Thunderbird

Tags: email, imap, yahoo

Помогите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема, через node-imap не подключается и так же не подключается  через thunderbird? Вот скрин:

http://joxi.ru/ZrJy9vjt1j440A

Через браузер заходит нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там надо выключать Less Secure (сам себе на вопрос дал ответ)